# Reporting task complementation status with only create and operation_date params

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables that the first one stores task data (task name, `create date`, assign_to etc) and the second table stores task history data e.g `operation_date`,task completed, task rejected etc. (Task and Task_history tables)

Company creates tasks and assign them to employees, then employees accepted tasks and complete them.

Task `create_date` column specify the  sequence of the task to do, both `operation_date` and `completed status` columns specify the sequence of the task complementation.

I need a query for reporting in employee detail that **Does An Employee complete the tasks in a sequence specified at the beginning ?  How many tasks completed accordance with the given sequence ?**

I tried a query for status completed tasks that order tables for task_creation and operation_date for an employee for a given day. Then, add the rownum for  select queries then join two tables. If rownums are equals, employee completes the task for given sequence else not. But the query result was not like what I expected. Rownums displaying like that,  `r_h--> 1,2,3 ; r_t--> 1,15,17`

```
    SELECT *
  FROM  (SELECT W.id, w.create_date, ROWNUM as r_t
            FROM wfm_task_1 W where W.task_status = 3
        ORDER BY W.create_date ASC) TASK_SEQ LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (  SELECT H.wfm_task, H.record_date, ROWNUM as r_h
            FROM wfm_task_history H
           WHERE H.task_status = 3
                 AND H.record_date BETWEEN (TO_DATE ('12.07.2013',
                                                     'DD.MM.YYYY')
                                            - 1)
                                       AND (TO_DATE ('12.07.2013',
                                                     'DD.MM.YYYY')
                                            + 1)
        ORDER BY H.record_date ASC) HISTORY_SEQ 

ON TASK_SEQ.id = HISTORY_SEQ.wfm_task
```

Sample dataset

```
wfm_task (ID, CREATION_DATE, TASK_NAME)

49361 | 06.07.2013 11:50:00 | missionx
49404 | 10.07.2013 13:01:00 | missiony
49407 | 11.07.2013 11:02:00 | missiona
49108 | 01.07.2013 21:02:00 | missionb

task_history (ID,WFM_TASK,OP_DATE, STATUS)

98 | 49361 | 12.07.2013 15:19:19 | 3 
92 | 49404 | 12.07.2013 11:10:50 | 3
90 | 49407 | 12.07.2013 11:06:58 | 3
78 | 49108 | 03.07.2013 11:02:00 | 1

result (WFM_TASK,RECORD_DATE,R_H,ID,CREATE_DATE,R_T)

49361 | 12.07.2013 15:19:19 | 3 | 49361 | 06.07.2013 11:50:00 | 15
49404 | 12.07.2013 11:10:50 | 2 | 49404 | 10.07.2013 13:01:00 | 17
49407 | 12.07.2013 11:06:58 | 1 | 49407 | 11.07.2013 11:02:00 | 1
```

Status 3 = completed. I want to find that  are the tasks completed by an order. I check that task complete order is likely to task creation order.

Comment: Showing some sample data and expected output would help.

Comment: What is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: 1-2-3 or 1-3-2   instead of 1-15-17. IF R_H and R_T columns equals, task completed ordered else not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to use [ROW_NUMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) function instead of ROWNUM.

```
SELECT a.id, a.create_date,
       row_number() over (order by a.create_date) r_t,
       b.record_date,
       row_number() over (order by b.record_date) r_h
from wfm_task a left outer join task_history b
                on a.id = b.wfm_task
 where b.status = 3
   and b.record_date between date'2013-07-12' - 1 and date'2013-07-12' + 1
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca505/4).

Comment: Woaw, perfect . Really thanks. Edited some of the columns and it works fine .